# how to remove underscore from a text which is linked by anchor tag in a locally run html file

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have an html file that organizes certain files scattered throughout my hard drive. But after saving file, my text i.e "Indian" got underlined. My code is

```
<a href="file:///G:\work files\project\indian.html" target="_blank">
   <div class="button-1">
      Indian
   </div>
</a>
```

My question: is there any rule or tag in css or html to remove that underscore?

I'd keep my `<div>` under `<a>`, so why text contained in `<div>` got underlined

Comment: Hello and welcome on SO: please take some time to carefully review and format properly your questions before posting

Comment: The link likely gets `text-decoration: underline` from the browser stylesheet - so overwrite that from within your own …

Comment: Also, a div in a link is not recommended (valid?)

Answer (score 0):

Add you must use css to change the way your links look like. Use a selector ("a") and set the `text-decoration` property to `none`:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>TITLE</title>
  <style>
    div a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>PAGE CONTENT</h1>
   <div>
      <a href="#">Link here</a>
   </div>
</body>

</html>
```